# minecraft command block testfor certain player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a command block that when powered, it will looks for a specific player in a 5 block radius of the command block. I tried

```
/testfor @p[r=5][name=<name of player>]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use two `[]` next to each other.

```
/testfor @p[r=5,name=<PlayerName>]
```

Use a comma to separate different values. Don't add another `[]` next to it.

Comment: This does not work either.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did not realize name is case Sensitive

Comment: can we test for name!=MyName ?

Comment: @Sivmatt we can, but Minecraft uses `name=!MyName` for that, i.e. "name equals (not MyName)". Same for other fields such as `type`

Comment: Will this work if there is one player closer to the command block? It seems like using `@a` instead of `@p` is better.