# What's wrong with this command block code?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to check if I am in a spesific area and I use command blocks for that: This is the code I use:

> testfor @p[r=4,name=<\miner11crafter>]

It should be right acording to this syntax I found on the [gamepadia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_Block):

> testfor @p[r=5,name=<\owner>]

`\` is neccesary for the formatting in SO otherwhise you can't see my name and stuff.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the link to where you found your information? But more to the point, you shouldn't be using angle brackets in the command.

Comment: here you go edited my question

Comment: Yeah, the use of angle brackets in that article is just conventional, meaning replace what's inside, plus the brackets themselves with your desired option, and that this option is required.

Comment: so it becomse... (I am not that good with this stuff)

Comment: Use `{` I believe?

Answer (score -3):

Here's a link that shows you how to use it:[minecraft command block testfor certain player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176706/minecraft-command-block-testfor-certain-player)

It says this should work:

> /testfor @p[r=5,name=player]

I just tested this on 1.8.1 and this worked.

Another problem could be that you are using { instead of [. Make sure you use the comma in between r=5 and name.

Comment: gives me this error: [17:39:50] Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char. also tried with {} instead of the <>

Comment: Which tutorial are you using?

Comment: theck the link in the question

Comment: There are multiple tutorials on that page

Comment: Secure Doors
By using a condition such as /testfor @p[r=5,name=<owner>], the command block can detect a door's owner within a certain radius and open a door for them, and only for them.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check the link

Comment: Do not just point people at an external link.  Summarize the information there, so that if the page ever goes down, your answer is still valid.

Comment: @Frank: It's actually a link to another question.  Which means this question should have been flagged as a dupe.

Comment: I just tested it on 1.8.1. I can confirm it works.

Comment: @Frank I fixed the problem you mentioned and mentioned some other things that could be causing trouble.