# Can this Minecraft command be inverted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I recently found out that `/testfor` can specify coordinates and player name. This gives me the idea that I could potentially make a command fueled door that only opens when my specific character is near it.

But can it be inverted? Meaning that it tests for anyone else besides me, and if someone is detected who isn't me, it then activates whatever I have attached to it. (For example, traps.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_kSKRCXcmI) and reading [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176706/minecraft-command-block-testfor-certain-player), I came up with the following for testing for other players.

```
testfor @p[r=5,name=!<your username>]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's =! and not !=? I don't know Minecraft that well but it's != in most programming languages.

Comment: @Probst Inori is correct, it is `=!`.

Comment: Well that's weird but OK lol