# Use the /testfor command with scoreboard, don't want to use @p or @a

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make a Minecraft shop but I **only** want myself accessing it, I've tried multiple variations of:

```
/testfor (nameofplayer) {score_ka1:1}
```

(ka1 is just another objective for amount of kills a player has)

Also, I **don't** want to replace (`nameofplayer`) with something like `@p` because it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't make it clear, for version 1.8.9

Comment: Why are you playing in 1.8.9? Maybe it would be easier to solve the problem you have with the current versions. 1.8.9 is almost 4 years old! It's also not officially supported anymore and you're unlikely to find tutorials or experts for it. Also, why do you want to use `/testfor`? It is usually not necessary in 1.8.9 and the cases where it is needed are pretty complicated and would require more explanation.

Comment: @FabianRöling I'm playing in 1.8.9 as I'm trying to make a KitPvP vanilla server and current versions are all weird with PvP, the `/testfor` is for detecting a certain player such as 'Notch' other than the closest player which could be anyone else. It is made so that every kill the player gets awarded one coin per kill, so every kill `ka1` then gets reset to zero and the certain player is awarded one coin. If `@p` was used, every kill someone got would give other people a coin and would mess up the shop system.

Comment: That's why newer Minecraft versions are better to use, you can do this probably with a single command now. And you can customise all aspects of PVP in newer versions as well, so that's not a good reason to stay in an extremely outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, found the answer myself at this post here: [minecraft command block testfor certain player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176706/minecraft-command-block-testfor-certain-player)

```
/testfor @p[score_(objective)_min=(n),name=(nameofplayer)]
```

`(objective)` to be replaced with objective (ka1 in this instance)

`(n)` to be the smallest number the objective (ka1 in this instance) can possibly be to get an output

`(nameofplayer)` to be replaced with the name of the player you are targeting.